# Showing Severity issue in Checkmarx 9 report for for Log forging

Tags: java, spring-boot, checkmarx

**This below is my code**

```
private String getCorrelationId(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String correlationId = null;        
    String valuesList = request.getHeader(CORRELATION_ID_HEADER);       
    String valueLists = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(valuesList);
    if (valueLists != null && !valueLists.isEmpty()) {
        correlationId = valueLists;
    }
    return correlationId;
}



private void startTransaction(HttpServletRequest request, String serviceName, Object... args) {
    String correlationId = getCorrelationId(request);
    String correlationIds = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(correlationId);                        
    if (correlationIds == null || correlationIds.isEmpty()) {
        logger.info(LOG_SERVICE_TYPE + serviceName + args);
    } else {
        logger.error(LOG_SERVICE_TYPE , serviceName , correlationIds , args);
    }
}
```

*Error Received*

> Method `getCorrelationId` gets user input from element `getHeader`. This element’s value flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated, and is eventually used in writing an audit log in `startTransaction`.
> This may enable **Log Forging**.

I have gone through some google links but not able to understand. any help would be appreciated

Comment: You don't understand what log forging is, or you don't understand why Checkmarx thinks it might happen here even though you use `escapeJava()`? What is `escapeJava()`? A link to docs might help on that front.

Comment: @ erikson as i am dealing this first time form the checkmarx report i have a little that log forging is where the sensitive information are recorded with logs that can be used by  attacker. But i am not sure how to resolve this scenario without changing the log...any help would be appreciated,

Comment: No, log forging is where an attacker controls what is written to the log file. They can alter the logging to hide their activity, or that can write malicious code into the log and then arrange for it to be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry on late answer on this..I have made many attempts to resolve this for checkmarks report here below.

1. `HtmlUtils.htmlEscape`  -> not worked
2. `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava` -> not worked

finally

1. `String cleanCorrelationId = correlationId.replace('\t', '_').replace('\n', '_').replace('\r', '_');`

and placed "cleanCorrelationId" in logging and `LogForging` issue resolved from checkmarks report.

Many thanks @Zvi Rosenfeld and @erickson

Answer (score 1):

Log Forging happens when an attacker can control a string that's written to the log (the "correlationId" in this case).
There are 2 dangers with this:

1. They can hide their tracks by changing the log (say, by adding a new line that says that they logged out).
2. Many times logs are loaded by monitoring tools. The attacker can inject a command or XSS to the log, hoping that the tools are vulnerable, and will run them.

You can read more about it [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Log_Injection).

In your case, the best solution would probably be to validate that the correlationId is in the expected format (assuming that the correlationId formant doesn't contain any specials characters. If it dose you should disallow them).